# load json data into li with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I can't load the data into a list with ng-repeat, here's my app

http://plnkr.co/edit/DD05TnnlG66H6nkLbJHM?p=preview

in line 12 of app.js I wrote

```
$scope.tabs = tabs;
```

which tabs is an object in `data.js`

One strange thing occur too, when I `console.log` something in my maincontroller scope, it tend to execute twice. I wonder

Comment: post relevant parts of the code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$scope.tabs.push` to add the data to the `tabs`. You can't do that because `$scope.tabs` is an object and not an array. Change the `data.js` to be like :

```
var tabs = [
    {
        'tabId':1,
        'tabName': 'Main',
        'Tabfriends':[
            {'name':'someone1'},
            {'name':'someone1'},
        ]
    },
    {
        'tabId':2,
        'tabName': 'Programming',
        'Tabfriends':[
            {'name':'someone2'}
        ]
    }
];
```

It's now an array, you can `push` it now. And AngularJS will also happy to `repeat` on it.

And also the tab object has `tabName` property, while on your `addTab` function you call it `name`.

Comment: right after $scope.tabs = tabs; I do a console.log, it seem to be execute 3 times, why?